# how to access a mounted device, How can I access the partitions with the console

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hi I'm new to ubuntu and linux so this might be a very begginers question.
I have several partitions on my pc and I want to be able to access them with the console.
When I type:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I get:

```
/dev/sda1   *        2048    97656831    48827392    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        97656832   234375167    68359168    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3   *   234375168   312500223    39062528   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       312502270   625141759   156319745    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       312502272   318359551     2928640   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       318361600   625141759   153390080   83  Linux
```

But it seams that the address is existing. for example I cant do cd /dev/sda4.
How can I access the partitions with the console?

Comment: you took a look in /mnt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see with `fdisk -l` are drives and their partitions. To use a partition of a drive you first have to mount the device.

Just typing `mount` will give you a list with the already mounted devices and their mount destination.

If you want to mount a partition, just type something like `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mydrive`.
You have to make sure that the folder `/mnt/mydrive` exists. (just type `mkdir -p /mnt/mydrive`)

The mount command then binds your partition to that folder. To mount you usually have to be root. So in ubunt type a `sudo` before mount.

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/mydrive
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mydive
```

To unmount the partition you use the `umount` command. Also take a look at `man mount` and `man fstab` if you are interrested in automatic mounts on startup.

*hth*

Answer (score 1):

to display mounted partitions:

```
df
```

or

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it dose the same as in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

it seams I find the solution:
when you type:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

you get the devices names, but if you want to find out the mounti position of a device then you write

```
mount
```

that gives you: device_name on mount_location 
now you can simply search for the mount_location and open it. Mine was:

```
/dev/sda2 on /media/6C7EFECD6DA2CD85 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```